# Не получается настроить мониторинг на Zabbix

Tags: linux, zabbix

Задача:
VM2 раз в 30 минут забиралась скорость скачивания и отдачи интернет трафика и передавалась на систему мониторинга VM1

На данный момент создал шаблон speedtest [image: Шаблон speedtest]

Но на графике нет никаких данных [image: График speedtest]

Подскажите что я делаю не так, в чем ошибка, почему не передаются данные с агента на сервер 7???

Comment: Ну чё, не нагугил? Мне тоже интересно.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен, нужно было настроить юзер параметры которые вычленяют нужные параметры из замера speedtest, активизировать шаблон в zabbix.